# NP-completeness of a problem using a "T-gadget"

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness

Working on a problem I came up with the following "T-gadget":
[image]

It has 3 connectors (A, B, C); each connector has two wires (A1,A2; B1,B2; C1,C2);
it can be rotated (0, 90, 180, 270 degrees);
two gadgets X and Y, can be linked together (one connector of X is joined with one connector of Y);
the wires used to link the T-gadgets cannot overlap.

A *signal* is propagated on the wires; and it can use *1 or 2 connectors* to traverse a T-gadget. Suppose that it enters through wire A1, then it can:

1. go back through wire A2, OR
2. choose among connector B or C - suppose that it chooses connector B; then it can exit the gadget through wire B1, re-enter through B2 and exit again through A2

When a signal enters a gadget and exits from the same connector, the gadget is "activated".

```
Possible traversals of a T-gadget:
(OUT) - A1 - A2 (OUT)
(OUT) - A1 - B1 - (OUT) - B2 - A2 - (OUT)
(OUT) - A1 - C1 - (OUT) - C2 - A2 - (OUT)
(OUT) - B1 - B2 (OUT)
(OUT) - B1 - A1 - (OUT) - A2 - B2 - (OUT)
(OUT) - B1 - C1 - (OUT) - C2 - B2 - (OUT)
(OUT) - C1 - C2 (OUT)
(OUT) - C1 - B1 - (OUT) - B2 - C2 - (OUT)
(OUT) - C1 - A1 - (OUT) - A2 - C2 - (OUT)
```

The signal starts on wire A1 of a gadget (with connector A unlinked) and must return to A2.

**Question**: is the problem: *"Given a set of T-gadgets linked together, does exist a path that activates all of them?"* $NP$-complete?

If we omit option 1 (*go back through wire A2)* I think that the problem is $NP$-complete (through reduction from Hamiltonian path problem on cubic planar graphs).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're asking whether the underlying 3-regular graph has a Hamiltonian path, which is NP-complete.  Your activation signal must traverse every edge in this path exactly twice.

See also [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/counting-the-number-of-hamiltonian-cycles-in-cubic-hamiltonian-graphs) and [this one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1651/hamiltonicity-of-k-regular-graphs).

Comment: @jeffe: now I see that option 1 *go back through wire A2* (without going further) does not alter the problem: it can (must) be used only at the end of the Hamiltonian path on the underlying cubic planar graph. Thank you! ... I'll wait a bit to see if other tiny variations (of the question) come up, otherwise I'll accept your answer.